# Why no error with unassigned variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a pupils model and a groups model. When adding a new pupil I have a collection_select box with :multiple=> true so that the pupil can be put into several groups.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "All Groups" %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:groups, :id, @all_groups,
                          :id, :name, {}, 
                          {:multiple => true}) %>
</div>
```

I have an edit pupil form that when loaded selects the groups the pupil was previously assigned so that they can be changed if needs be so has the extra bit in {} in the collection select options;

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "All Groups" %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:groups, :id, @all_groups,
                          :id, :name, {selected: @previous_selection},
                          {:multiple => true}) %>
</div>
```

the @previous_selection is set in the pupils_controller;

```
  @previous_selection = Array.new
    @pupil.groups.each do |pg|
    @previous_selection.push(pg.id)
end
```

This is in the def edit block so only setup for the edit page.

Here is the PupilsController;

```
class PupilsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_pupil, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@pupils = Pupil.all
end

def show
  @pupil_groups = @pupil.groups
end


def new
@pupil = Pupil.new
@all_groups = set_pupil_list
end

def edit
  @all_groups = set_pupil_list

  @previous_selection = Array.new
   @pupil.groups.each do |pg|
  @previous_selection.push(pg.id)
end
end


def create
@pupil = Pupil.new(pupil_params)
clean_select_multiple_params
logger.debug "The groups parameter contains: #{params[:groups][:id]}"
selected_groups = Group.find(params[:groups][:id])
@pupil.groups = selected_groups

respond_to do |format|
  if @pupil.save
    format.html { redirect_to @pupil, notice: 'Pupil was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @pupil }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @pupil.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @pupil.update(pupil_params)
    clean_select_multiple_params
    selected_groups = Group.find(params[:groups][:id])
    @pupil.groups = selected_groups
    format.html { redirect_to @pupil, notice: 'Pupil was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @pupil.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
@pupil.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to pupils_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end

def full_name
@fn = @pupil.given_name
@sn = @pupil.surname
@full_name = @fn + @sn
end

private

def set_pupil
  @pupil = Pupil.find(params[:id])
end

def set_pupil_list
Group.all
end


def clean_select_multiple_params hash = params
hash.each do |k, v|
  case v
  when Array then v.reject!(&:blank?)
  when Hash then clean_select_multiple_params(v)
end
end
end

def pupil_params
  params.require(:pupil).permit(:given_name, :surname, :date_of_birth, :gender, :ethnicity)
end
end
```

When the new pupil page is requested the _form.html.erb file is used that has the {selected:   @previous_selection} argument in it that has not been set up by def new in the pupils_controller but there is not a error message about @previous_selection not being initialized.

I would expect an error but am not getting one but do not understand why. Could someone please explain? I am new to programming in general so sorry if I am using the wrong terminolog.

Thank you

Leon

Comment: is `before_filter :action` present in your controller?

Comment: Hi Nithin, I have added the PupilsController code. No before_filter :action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@previous_selection` variable is `nil`, and hence in the view none of `collection` items will be selected. It is not necessary to initialize a `variable` to `nil`, **rails** does that.